# How to check elasticsearch tokens after running a query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

My problem is the following:

I run an elasticsearch query in a rails app using specific settings to my index and my search analyzer, the problem is that it doesnt return any results in the app, in the other hand when i try to run it directly from my elasticsearch docker, i have tokens returned. If i use these tokens in my app query, i get results...

so this is my elasticsearch query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/development-stoot-services/_analyze?analyzer=search_francais' -d 'cours de guitare'
{"tokens":[{"token":"cour","start_offset":0,"end_offset":5,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"guitar","start_offset":9,"end_offset":16,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":3}]}
```

here is the query from my rails app to elasticsearch:

```
query = {
   "query" : {
     "bool" : {
       "must" : [
         {
           "range" : {
             "deadline" : {
               "gte" : "2016-05-26T10:27:19+02:00"
             }
           }
         },
         {
           "terms" : {
             "state" : [
               "open"
             ]
           }
         },
         {
           "query_string" : {
             "query" : "cours de guitare",
             "default_operator" : "AND",
             "fields" : [
               "title",
               "description",
               "brand",
               "category_name"
             ]
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   },
   "filter" : {
     "and" : [
       {
         "geo_distance" : {
           "distance" : "40km",
           "location" : {
             "lat" : 48.855736,
             "lon" : 2.32927300000006
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   },
   "sort" : [
     {
       "created_at" : "desc"
     }
   ]
 }
```

the last query does not return any result, but if i try a query with the tokens returned by elasticsearch ('cour', 'guitar') i have expected results. So i guess there is a problem between rails and elasticsearch that i dont find...
Can anyone help on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your query like this, i.e. you need to specify the `search_francais` analyzer in your `query_string` in order to analyze `cours de guitare` the same way you did with the `_analyze` endpoint:

```
     ...
     {
       "query_string" : {
         "query" : "cours de guitare",
         "default_operator" : "AND",
         "analyzer": "search_francais",       <--- add this line
         "fields" : [
           "title",
           "description",
           "brand",
           "category_name"
         ]
       }
     },
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Val ! it did the job :)
but i have another question thought, i tried and thought that i can specify a default analyzer for searching queries when indexing datas. Is there any possible way to do that ?

Comment: Yes, you need to define a [default analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html) either in your index settings (i.e. define an analyzer called "default_search") or directly in your mapping by specifying a `search_analyzer` on your field(s) or on the `_all` field.